# Find all topological sorts in a DAG using BGL (Boost graph library)

Tags: c++, boost, topological-sort

How can use the Boost Graph Library to find all the topological sorts of a given DAG `G`?

I have found some theoretical references explaining that is possible, there's also this [code](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/all-topological-sorts-of-a-directed-acyclic-graph/) where there's an implementation. But I don't actually want to start from scratch, and I want to use BGL to compute them.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy would be to get all vertices without predecessors (no directed edges to it). And multiplying vectors based on vertices without predecessors. If you have a C++ to do it please share.

The code to get depth_first topological sort:

Given a DAG `graph` with vertex type `vertex_t`:

```
deque<vertex_t> topologicalSorted;

//perform topological sort
if (topologicalSort(graph, topologicalSorted)) {
    cout << "The graph is directed acyclic!" << endl;
    cout << "Topological order: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < topologicalSorted.size(); i++) {
        cout << graph[topologicalSorted.at(i)].label << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
} 


bool topologicalSort()
{
    try
    {
        boost::topological_sort(graph, front_inserter(topologicalSorted));
    }
    catch (boost::not_a_dag)
    {
        cout << "not a dag\n";
        return false;
    }
    cout << "top sort OK\n";

    return true;
}
```

Without custom vertex:

```
deque<int> topologicalSorted;

if (topologicalSort()) {
        // Print the results.
        for (int i = 0; i < topologicalSorted.size(); i++) {
            cout << topologicalSorted.at(i) << ",";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```